# Are .NET window form events (e.g. button click) synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: .net, forms

My understanding is that they are synchronous, however in the project I am currently working on, when I double click on a button it ends up calling the method twice, but the seconds call is made before the long running first call returns.

I know that I can prevent this by disabling the button on the first click, but I'd like to know if they are sync or async?

Thanks,
Canice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends how the Window Form was setup and programmed.  If the UI is running in it's own thread or the button clicks are wired up to run as a background request you would see them as Async events.  However if they weren't wired up this way, they you will see them as Sync events.

So with out knowing more about how this Windows Form was programmed, the answer is **it depends**.

Comment: The form is pretty standard and when I look at the list of threads in the debugger the event handler call is on the main thread. 
Where can i check if the button clicks are wired up as background requests?

Comment: Well first is the request spawning up a new thread from what you can see in the debugger?  If it isn't then there is no background worker thread.

Comment: No I'm not creating a new thread for handle the event. 

However it is talking to an existing thread using a pair of AutoResetEvent, one for indicate that a new 'command' is ready and the other the other to indicate that it's processed. I'm using WaitOne(timeout) method to wait for each command to be processed/timeout.

The thread runs continously sending commands over TCP to a piece of equipment

However I don't believe that the threading/AutoResetEvents is causing the problem as they are still waiting for a response when the second click event is received - but I'm probably wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

They are *synchronous* but not *serialized*. There is the possibility of reentrancy.

It sounds like your button click handler runs a nested message loop, directly or indirectly. In this case, the handler can be invoked again before the first one returns.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that sounds like the problem. Is the 'standard' way of handling this to disable the button until the first event is handled or is there a better way?

Comment: It depends on the "look and feel" that you want for your UI, and what the button represents. Disabling the button while the handler is running is one common approach; this is an easy solution and one users see all the time in web pages. Or you may want to bring up a modal "busy" dialog if you want to disable the entire UI. Or - if you don't want to disable anything - you can have the button add an "in-progress task" to a list of tasks in the UI, so the user can see the button did something and see when the task completes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, not usually, although the way the windows message pump works may sometimes simulate it.  Of course it also depends on how you define "synchronous" and "asynchronous".

In general, when you click a button, the GUI thread does not usually return until the method and any synchronous methods it calls are done.  This is why the UI will "freeze up" when doing cpu intensive work in an event handler.

Comment: Based on Stephen's reply above, what I need to know is whether they are serialised or not.